# Method to reverse a string

Tags: python, string

Hi I'm trying to reverse a string with the following code. Does anyone see the bug here?

```
def reverse(string):
    length = len(string)
    last = length -1
    middle = length/2
    newstring = []
    for i in range(middle):
            newstring[i] = string[last -i]
            newstring[last -i] = string[i]
    return ''.join(newstring)
```

Comment: In case you didn't know, `string[::-1]` reverses the string as well.

Comment: @Jin I know that works, I just want to know how I can do it this way.

Comment: When you have code that produces an error, please post the traceback as well.

Comment: You appear to be asking homework questions. You need to _tag them homework_ and then you won't get lots of answers that don't help, and people who post helpful "manual" solutions won't get downvoted.

Comment: That said, you're close. If you replace `newstring = []` with `newstring = list(string)` it will work. I'll leave it to you to improve it beyond just working.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple bugs:

1. You can't index into an empty list: `newstring[i]` and `newstring[last -i]`.
2. You always add characters in pairs, so the result (if other bugs are fixed) always has an even length, even if the input string had an odd length.

There may be more.

Lastly, I think you're making it too hard for yourself:

```
In [1]: 'abcdef'[::-1]
Out[1]: 'fedcba'
```

This uses the slicing syntax, which is `start:stop:step`. By omitting `start` and `stop` we're taking the entire string, and `step=-1` simply means that we're taking the characters in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `newstring[last-i]`, right? That should return an index error.

Comment: Sure; just let the `for` loop go over `range(length)`. `newstring = ''; for i in range(length): newstring += string[last-i]`. Before others complain, I am aware that this is very slow. I'm assuming that this is only an exercise.

Comment: @cfarm54 `newstring=[None]*len(string)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
def reverse(string):
        tmp=[]
        for c in string:
            tmp.insert(0,c)
        return ''.join(tmp)
```

Comment: Cool. Can you do it without using any pre-defined functions?

Answer (score 0):

You're going out of range because you're directly assigning to an index of an empty list.  On the first pass you reference the nonexistent `newstring[0]`.

Do not use the name "string".  It is the name of a common Python module that you may end up importing.  Looking at this, most people wouldn't know if you were referring to the module here or not.

If you want to do the whole manual list manipulation thing for the sake of pedagogy, you're better off treating the source string as a stack and the destination list as a queue, popping off the source and enqueueing on the destination:

```
def reverse(source):
    source = list(source)
    dest = []
    while source:
        dest.append(source.pop())
    return ''.join(dest)
```

In general, you shouldn't have to use numeric indexing in Python for operations that affect the entire collection uniformly.  If you find yourself in that situation you're most likely thinking too low-level.

I would personally use extended slice notation:

`"hello world"[::-1]`

Leaving off the first argument of a slice means "the beginning of the list".  Leaving off the second argument of a slice means "the end of the list".  The third argument represents the step by which the list is traversed.  By stepping negatively you traverse the list in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
"".join(reversed("abc"))
```

But probably is not as efficient as aix's [Method to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729347/method-to-reverse-a-string/7729428#7729428).